# RSA Authentication Issue

Tags: java, authentication, rsa

I'm making a system where I want to verify the server's identity via RSA, but I can't seem to get the server to properly decrypt the client's message.

The public and private keys are in slot 0 of the array, and mod is in slot 1, so they are setup correctly.

**Client side code**

```
int keyLength = 3072 / 8;//RSA key size
byte[] data = new byte[keyLength];

//Generate some random data. Note that
//Only the fist half of this will be used.
new SecureRandom().nextBytes(data);

int serverKeySize = in.readInt();
if (serverKeySize != keyLength) {//Definitely not the right heard
    return false;
}

//Take the server's half of the random data and pass ours
in.readFully(data, keyLength / 2 , keyLength / 2);

//Encrypt the data
BigInteger[] keys = getKeys();
BigInteger original = new BigInteger(data);
BigInteger encrypted = original.modPow(keys[0], keys[1]);
data = encrypted.toByteArray();

out.write(data);

//If the server's hash doesn't match, the server has the wrong key!
in.readFully(data, 0, data.length);

BigInteger decrypted = new BigInteger(data);

return original.equals(decrypted);
```

**Server side code**

```
int keyLength = 3072 / 8;//Key length
byte[] data = new byte[keyLength];

//Send the second half of the key
out.write(data, keyLength / 2, keyLength / 2);
in.readFully(data);

BigInteger[] keys = getKeys();
BigInteger encrypted = new BigInteger(data);
BigInteger original = encrypted.modPow(keys[0], keys[1]);
data = original.toByteArray();

out.write(data);
```

AFAIK that implementation is correct however it doesn't seem to produce the correct output. Also no, I do not wish to use a Cipher for various reasons.

Comment: Rule number one when it comes to crypto algorithms is never to implement an existing algorithm yourself. use the existing, known to be correctly working implementations, e.g. provided by Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some critical details that are not being accounted for. The data you want to apply RSA to must be encoded as BigInteger x, with 0 <= x < n, where n is your modulus. You aren't doing that. In fact, because you are filling your entire data array with random data you cannot guarantee that. The PKCS#1 padding algorithm is designed to do this correctly, but since you are rolling your own you'll have to fix this in your code. Also, examine carefully how the `BigInteger(byte[])` constructor and `BigInteger.toByteArray()` decode/encode integers. Naively many expect simply the base 256 encoding, and forget that BigInteger must accommodate negative integer also. It does so by using the ASN.1 DER integer rules. If the positive integer's high-order byte would be >= 128 then a leading zero byte is added.